# Reading a protobuf3 custom option from C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

**TL;DR**

According to the doc, if I were doing C++, I could read the value of a custom option using `string value = MyMessage::descriptor()->options().GetExtension(my_option);`. There are similar examples for Java and Python. But I'm doing C# and I could find an equivalent. Can I do it, and if yes, how?

**More details**

I'm manipulating classes generated with [protobuf3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Protobuf.Tools/). The schemas are declaring a [custom option](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#customoptions). It looks like this:

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions {
  string my_option = 51234;
}

message MyMessage {
  option (my_option) = "Hello world!";
}
```

My code is being provided an object generated from `MyMessage`, and I'd like to read the value of this option (here `Hello world!`)

---

Update: I'm not using protobuf-net. Now that C# is natively supported by protobuf, I'm using Google's protobuf3 C# library.

Comment: @Sinatr Hmm, why do you think that? In my opinion this seems quite a clearly written and different question. Custom options are an advanced protobuf feature that is not used very often but can be quite useful. Also, this seems to be about Google's protobuf3 C# library and not protobuf-net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the feature hasn't been implemented yet: https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/1603

It also looks like it's only a matter of time and they're open to pull requests. So depending on how soon you need it, you could be the one doing the implementation :)

Answer (score 3):

You can now access custom options in C#. First, define the custom option in your .proto:

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";
extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
  string objectReferenceType = 1000; //Custom options are 1000 and up.
}
```

Next, apply the custom option to something. Here I attached it to a field:

```
message Item
{
  string name = 1;
  int32 id = 2;
  string email = 3;
  ObjectReference prefab = 4 [(objectReferenceType) = "UnityEngine.GameObject"];
}
```

Then you need to lookup the custom option field number. There's no nice way to do this, so just look up the extension from FileDescriptor of the file where you defined the custom option extension. You will have a C# generated class called protoFileNameReflection. From that, you can find the extension then the field number. Here's an example assuming the proto is called "Item.proto" so the generated class is called ItemReflection:

```
foreach (FieldDescriptor extensionFieldDescriptor in ItemReflection.Descriptor.Extensions.UnorderedExtensions)
    {   
        if (extensionFieldDescriptor.ExtendeeType.FullName == "google.protobuf.FieldOptions")
        {
            objectReferenceTypeFieldNumber = extensionFieldDescriptor.FieldNumber;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Then access the custom option in code using protobuf reflection:

```
FieldDescriptor fieldDescriptor = prefabFieldDescriptor;
CustomOptions customOptions = fieldDescriptor.CustomOptions;
if (customOptions.TryGetString(objectReferenceTypeFieldNumber, out string objectReferenceTypeText))
{
   Console.Log(objectReferenceTypeText); //logs: "UnityEngine.GameObject"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the C# compiler doesn't generate any option information into the cs file. Can it be, that this feature is not yet implemented in the protobuf compiler for C#?

Comment: @ErikStroeken I had it working for like a month, then in October it broke, then the Protobuf C# team said it should be working again in 3.11 (I have not tried 3.11). The other trick is that the custom option lives in the FileDescriptor where the extension is defined. I couldn't get at it from the MessageDescriptor.

Comment: @ErikStroeken I confirmed that it is all working again in 3.11. I should note that FieldDescriptor.CustomOptions is marked as deprecated, but the preferred GetOption<> replacement method doesn't make any sense to me as it requires an Extension reference which I can't seem to find anywhere.

Comment: @AliZeinali The main, absolute most important gotcha is that the FieldDescriptor for the extension has to come from the reflection FILE that contains the extension. So if you define FieldOptions extension in file Monkey.proto, you must get the field descriptor from MonkeyReflection. Also, you should be able to debug and see where it's failing (and tell me, so I can help you. Just saying it doesn't work doesn't really help me help you.) Also, you can just use a hardcoded FieldNumber (in my example 1000).

Comment: To use the `GetOption` method, you need to pass in the strongly typed `Extension` object which you get from the file descriptor where the original option was defined, and then just cast it to `Extension<FileOptions, MyCustomOption>`.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the answer for Protobuf 3.11.4 as this is the only thread dealing with the problem. Using similar protos as DoomGoober:

```cs
// Foo.proto
Package foo
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";
extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
  string objectReferenceType = 1000; //Custom options are 1000 and up.
}
```

```cs
// Bar.proto
import "Foo.proto"
message Item
{
  string name = 1;
  int32 id = 2;
  string email = 3;
  ObjectReference prefab = 4 [(foo.objectReferenceType) = "UnityEngine.GameObject"];
}
```

You can read the custom options from an Item Proto object using a new generated class. In this case its called **FooExtensions** (see Foo.protos):

```cs
public void LogFieldOptions(Item item)
{
  // Get the list of fields in the message (name, id, etc...)
  var fieldDescriptors = item.Descriptor.Fields.InFieldNumberOrder();

  foreach (var fieldDescriptor in fieldDescriptors)
  {
    // Fetch value of this item instance for current field
    var fieldValue = fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(item);

    // Fetch name of field
    var fieldName = fieldDescriptor.Name;

    // if we are not in the correct field: Skip    
    if(!fieldName.Equals("prefab")) continue;

    // Fetch the option set in this field in the proto
    // (note that this is not related to the instance 
    // of item but to the general item message descriptor)
    var optionObjectReferenceType = fieldDescriptor.GetOption(FooExtensions.objectReferenceType); 
    Console.Log(optionObjectReferenceType ); //logs: "UnityEngine.GameObject";
  }
}
```

You are able to fetch all types of options in the same way (MessageOptions, FileOptions). Simply ensure you are using the correct descriptor (For MessageOptions use MessageDescriptors and so on...)

Comment: GetOption() is obsolete, use GetOptions().GetExtension(FooExtensions.objectReferenceType)

Comment: Adding to @slfan 's answer: string optionValue = componentFieldDescriptor.GetOptions().GetExtension<string>(FooExtensions.ObjectReferenceType); The GetExtension template type has to match the type of the field you are adding to FieldOptions, which in this case is string.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reading Custom Message Options (Extensions)

- Assuming the file is called `foobar.proto`

```cs
message.Descriptor.GetOptions().GetExtension(FoobarExtensions.MyOption);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple version to access the descriptor data:

```
public void LogFieldOptions(Item item)
{
   var fieldDescriptors = item.Descriptor.Fields.InDeclarationOrder(); // or .InFieldNumberOrder()
   var fieldDescriptor = fieldDescriptors.FirstOrDefault(fd => fd.Name == "prefab")

   if (fieldDescriptor != null)
   {
       var objectReferenceType = fieldDescriptor.GetOptions().GetExtension(FooExtensions.objectReferenceType); 
       // use result
   }
}
```

Comment: As of 3.11.4 GetExtension() requires a template type:  var objectReferenceType = fieldDescriptor.GetOptions().GetExtension<string>(FooExtensions.objectReferenceType); The template type should match the type of the field you added to FieldOptions. If you hover over FooExtensions.objectReferenceType your IDE will tell you the type of objectReferenceType and the second template value should match the template value of GetExtension<>().