# Reflection in gRPC \ Protobuf in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, protocol-buffers, grpc

Due to the lack of examples in C#, I can't get reflection in gRPC\Protobuf working. One application would be supplying a version of all interfaces and messages.

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

option csharp_namespace = "Addressbook.Services";

extend google.protobuf.FileOptions {
  string version = 50000;
}

option (version) = "1.2.3.0";

service AddressBookService {
...
```

Is it possible that a client parses the connected server with reflection? Is the `version` supplied to all interfaces and messages? How to I do that in C#?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Why do you want/ need to do this with reflection?

Comment: Okay. Ask the question in a different way: how (if at all) can the client obtain the content of the custom file option 'version' of the interfaces and messages defined at the server? A C# example would help.

Comment: One google search and 2 minutes of reading lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58774500/9363973) SO answer. Seems like google is using some custom reflection, not the normal .NET reflection

Comment: Now I get it why nothing works what I tried. Reflection is not yet implemented in C#. See: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/1603.

Comment: The C# API does support custom options](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2143). This issue is linked by John Skeet himself on the issue you linked and has been merged since the 2nd November 2016. Custom MessageOption can be accesed via Protobuf.Descriptor.GetOptions(..) as shown [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2143#issuecomment-259076892). But since 4th of Januar 2017 you need to use the CustomOptions class

Comment: Custom options are part of the schema, not part of the payload. They are not sent with the data. This approach will not achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to see if client and server are in sync with all .proto files.

Here's a solution that will have to be tweaked but otherwise will work.

This only works if server has reflection enabled - maybe not an option everywhere.

In `ServiceName.Descriptor.File` `ServiceName` refers to class generated by protoc.

```cs
        using var channel = _channelFactory.GetChannel();
        var client = new ServerReflection.ServerReflectionClient(channel);
        
        using var call = client.ServerReflectionInfo();

        // To get all service names on the server, you can use this:
        // await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new ServerReflectionRequest{ ListServices = ""});
        // await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None);
        // foreach (var serviceResponse in call.ResponseStream.Current.ListServicesResponse.Service)
        // {
        //     _logger.LogInformation("Service name on server: {ServiceName}", serviceResponse.Name);
        // }
        
        await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new ServerReflectionRequest{FileContainingSymbol = "name.space.service_name"});
        await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None);
        var descriptorResponse = call.ResponseStream.Current;
        
        // This list has to be reversed. Check `.BuildFromByteStrings` docstring for more info.
        var fileDescriptors = FileDescriptor.BuildFromByteStrings(descriptorResponse.FileDescriptorResponse.FileDescriptorProto.Reverse());
        var localDescriptor = ServiceName.Descriptor.File;
        var relevantFileDescriptor = fileDescriptors.Single(descriptor => descriptor.Name == localDescriptor.Name);

        if (relevantFileDescriptor.SerializedData != localDescriptor.SerializedData)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Remote .proto differs from local copy. Please update.");
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(".proto definition matches between client and server.");
        }

        await call.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
```