# Protobuf3 - Protobuf-net get Options/Extensions from C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have an `opt.proto` file that has the following structure:

```
extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions {
  repeated string class_attr = 3003;
}

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
  repeated string field_attr = 3004;
}
```

and another `classext.proto` that has the import from the `opt.proto` file:

```
message Stream
{
    option (class_attr) = "TestClassAttribute";
    option (class_attr) = "TestClassAttribute2";
    
    string id = 1 [(field_attr) = "TestFieldAttribute", (field_attr) = "TestFieldAttribute"];
    
    string description = 2;

    string path = 3;
}
```

When compiling I need to have access to the extensions and their values so I can add more information when needed. So far I can only access the name of the fields (class_attr, field_attr), but I can't access their values.

I saw that for c++ there is something like `GetExtension(option)`.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124296/8469314) in 2016, there was no such type of implementation,

Has this been resolved in any way?

Merci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I ended up creating my own reader that loads the information so I can scroll through as needed.